# Start timer on page load, record time in DB

Tags: php, html

I'm looking to create a website form that when it loads a timer is started and on submit the time it took to complete in recorded into database. I'm not sure how to even start to make this happen. I've tried finding example source codes and no luck. It's not a countdown and i need to be able to print the time it took to complete into database.

If you are able to link example of this i would be very great full.

Comment: One approach would be to call the PHP time() function when generating the form and putting the value in a hidden field. When the user submits, this start time would be passed to the script that is called. In that script, you would call the time() function again to get the end time. Subtract the two to get the elapsed time. How does this sound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this JS Count down timer(given below) and then send value to DB on submit.

```js
var sec = 00; // set the seconds
var min = 00; // set the minutes

function countDown() {
  sec++;
  if (sec == 59) {
    sec = 00;
    min = min + 1;
  } else {
    min = min;
  }
  if (sec <= 9) {
    sec = "0" + sec;
  }
  time = (min <= 9 ? "0" + min : min) + " min and " + sec + " sec ";
  if (document.getElementById('time')) {
    var theTime = document.getElementById('time');
    theTime.innerHTML = time;
  }
  SD = window.setTimeout("countDown();", 1000);
  if (min == '05' && sec == '00') {
    window.clearTimeout(SD);
    alert("Too slow.");
  }
}

function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  }
  else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}

addLoadEvent(function() {
  var el = document.getElementById("startButton");
  el.addEventListener("click", countDown, false);
});
```

```html
<body onload="countDown()">
  <div id="time"></div>
</body>
```

*This prints "Too slow" if it takes more than 5mins.*

Get the value for the div using getElementByID & save it to db using an [insert command](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp).

Comment: this is exactly what I'm looking for thank you!